# php script idea to send me email when my Windows hangs

Tags: php, windows, web-services, batch-file

I'm facing a challenge here. My windows 10 PC needs to run all the time, with some programs running on it. However, as a commonplace about windows, it does hang/freeze/BSOD once in a while, randomly. And since I'm not in front of it all the time, sometimes I won't know that it's stuck, for long, till I check it and have to manually hard restart it.
To overcome this problem I'm thinking of an idea like this:

1. Some program (probably .bat file) can be set to run in the PC, that sends a ping (or some message) to a webservice running remotely, every 10 mins or so.
2. A PHP script (the webservice) running in my host server (I own a hosting space for my website) can listen to this particular ping (or message), and wait.
3. If this webservice doesn't receive the ping (or msg) when expected, it simply sends out an email notifying the same.
4. So whenever the windows hangs/freezes, that .bat file would stop sending as well, triggering the notification from the websvc in the next 10 mins.

This is an idea, but frankly I still don't know how to actually achieve it technically, and whether it's truly feasible. Also, I'm not sure if I'm missing something crucial in terms of server load, etc.

Would greatly appreciate any help with the idea, and if possible pointers to the script that I can put on the server. Also, I'm not sure how to set it up to listen continuously.

Can someone please help here?

Comment: How do you expect your computer to do anything if it freezes or BSODs?

Comment: I think the point is that the lack of a signal from the windows10 pc on it's scheduled time will trigger the server to send an email rather than the pc do anything further

Comment: Maybe install PHP on the PC and have it serve one page. Then your host can just request that page at an interval and if it fails it can assume there is a problem with the PC.

Comment: Perhaps `packetsender` or similar would be of interest/use? https://packetsender.com/

Comment: @RamRaider Thanks for the suggestion. Packetsender seems to one part of the puzzle. But the 2nd part of sending mail, when no packet recieved? Does't seem to me, that it can handle this functionality... Any suggestions?

Comment: @Warren I thought of that idea, but due to security reasons, I don't really want to make a server on this PC and expose it to outside for incoming connections. I'd rather send out something, than get something in.

Comment: The server you have - windows or *nix?

Comment: @RamRaider Server is *nix hosted on the web. May I know the context of your question?

Comment: it is easy enough on the windows pc to send an http request every N minutes ( scheduled task etc ) so the problem is how to process that at the server. I was toying with the idea of a php script to intercept the http request and trigger an event to be logged in the system log. How that log is processed is very much OS dependant.

Comment: Yes, That's almost what I'm also trying to figure out. On the server side, what I intend to do is, to intercept this http request from the windows, but also to check if there's no such request in the last 10 mins. That absence of request would be my trigger to send an email notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

Have your web service on your host comprise of one page, one database and one cron job.

The database has one table with one record that holds a time.

The cron job checks the the database-table-record every 10 minutes and if the time in the record is in the past, the cron sends you an email.

The page, when requested, simply updates the record to be the current time + 10 minutes. Have your Windows machine request this page every 10 minutes.

So essentially, the cron job is ready to send you an email, but it never can because the PC is always requesting a page to reset the time - until it can't.

Comment: Wow... Seems like a great idea! Lemme try this and will update you. Thanks @Warren

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so here's how I Finally achieved this whole idea, as suggested by @Warren above.

1. Created a simple db table in mysql in my hosting server, with just 2
   fields, id and next_time.
2. Created a simple php page, which inserts/updates the current time + 10mins into the above table.
3. Created a python script, that checks in this table, if the time stored is < the current time. If yes, then sends a mail to me.
4. Scheduled this python script as cron job to run every 10 mins.
5. Thus when the PC hangs, for more than 10 mins, the script would let me know.

Thanks a lot for the help in coming up with this plan. Hope this helps someone else thinking of a similar thing to do.

*Improvisation*: I moved the above codes to my local raspberry pi web server, to remove dependency on the remote hosting server.

*Next step*: I'm planning to let the python script on the raspberry pi control a relay, which would toggle the reset switch of the PC, when the above event happens. So, not only would I know when the windows goes on BSOD, but it'll also be restarted on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as a next step, I made some more simplification to the solution for the original requirement.

No more PHP now. Just one Python Script, and a small hardware improvement.

1. As I'm still learning new ways with this Raspberry Pi, I now connected the RPi to the PC via ethernet cable as a peer-to-peer connection.
2. Enabled ping response from Windows, [as per this link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/how-to-enable-ping-response-in-windows-7/5aff5f8d-f138-4c9a-8646-5b3a99f1cae6?auth=1).
3. Then wrote another python script to simply ping the windows PC (with a static IP for ethernet adapter)
4. If the ping fails, then send the email as the earlier script.
5. As earlier, setup this new script as the cron job to run every 10 mins, instead of the earlier script.
6. So if the windows hangs, I assume the ping would fail too, and thus an email would be sent out.

Thus now the web-server and database are both eliminated from the equation.

Still waiting for the Relay module to arrive, so I can implement the *next step* of automatic hard reboot.